# Vlookup Several CSV with No Headers in R

Tags: r, excel, merge, inner-join, vlookup

I have several csv files with no headers and the only commonality is the first column that always has the users unique ID. Using R, I want to create either one/two csv file(s) that combines specific information based on the user ID chosen.

So for example there is:

table 1 (which has no header but for guidance the columns are ID, Name, Birthday)

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | James  | Nov-00 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| 78397 | Tom    | Jul-20 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| 73820 | Pan    | Sep-10 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| 64920 | Kim    | Nov-01 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| 83915 | Amanda | Jan-03 |
+-------+--------+--------+
| 83649 | Linda  | Jul-07 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

and table 2 (which has no header but for guidance the columns are ID, Product Category, Purchase in 2012, Purchase in 2013, Purchase in 2014, Purchase in 2015)

```
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 1 | 500000 | 600000 | 700000 | 800000 |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 2 | 333    | 456    | 567    | 467    |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 3 | 444    | 456    | 399    | 799    |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 4 | 20000  | 4000   | 3222   | 3456   |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 5 | 21305  | 23456  | 3567   | 8533   |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 80938 | 6 | 345067 | 2455   | 23356  | 244567 |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

and I want to create either the combined table below

```
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID: 80938        |        |        |        |        |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name: James      |        |        |        |        |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Birthday: Nov-00 |        |        |        |        |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Product: 1       |        |        |        |        |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|                  | 2012   | 2013   | 2014   | 2015   |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Purchase         | 500000 | 600000 | 700000 | 800000 |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

or these two tables:

1.

```
   +------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | ID: 80938        |        |        |        |        |
    +------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Name: James      |        |        |        |        |
    +------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Birthday: Nov-00 |        |        |        |        |
    +------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | Product: 1       |        |        |        |        |
    +------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

2. 

and this table which is based on the ID chosen

```
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|                  | 2012   | 2013   | 2014   | 2015   |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Purchase         | 500000 | 600000 | 700000 | 800000 |
+------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Why do you want your data in a format with all those missing values? Wouldn't it be better to just left join by ID? Otherwise any subsequent analysis tasks are going to be much harder (and will essentially involve having to reshape into a left-joined format anyway) Is this purely for display purposes?

Comment: If a third party came in and only saw the csv files (which let says is over 100 csv files) with no headers and all that information they'd be confused. Allowing someone to simply adjust the ID &/ product number allows them to get the information they need in a manner they can understand

Comment: It's not just the missing values, like @AllanCameron says, it's also that in your final format you now have headers to the left and headers in the middle of the data. Messy.

Comment: If the problem is the missing headers in the original files, a better option is to assign headers leaving the format as it is now. It seems that you have several tables, in the example `customers` and `purchases`. It's a good idea to have them separated from one another. In fact, it's even a design goal in some languages (SQL).

Comment: Adding headers to several csv doesn't solve my desire to have an option to show only the needed information associated with someone's ID.

Comment: Also, if the problem is the final format then I'd like 2 create 2 tables. Table one being row 1-4 (of the final table above) and table two being row 5-6. But I don't understand why the final format cannot exist as is. I don't think it's messy.